# script runtime errors

Tags: internet-explorer, script

I have checked disable scripting (both) in Internet Explorer tools (and it stays checked) and am still getting frequent runtime error boxes.  it happens with chrome open, but not Internet Explorer. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are disabling this in Internet Options, that is only for Internet Explorer and not for Chrome.

As for disabling it in Chrome - I am not exactly sure as I haven't seen many errors (And do not use Chrome that much). I thought you only see errors with the Developer Tools open. Can you give a site this occurs on and I will see what I can find.

Comment: it happens with a chrome browser window open (typically 'news' and 'mail' tabs open) and nothing else going on...